# JFrog Artifactory doesn't generate dependency declaration

Tags: gradle, dependencies, artifactory, publisher, jfrog-cli

I created default repository for gradle and published jar into it. I don't see snippets with dependency declaration on the JAR description page. 
I have only added a local repository. What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that your file is not deployed according to the Maven/Gradle layout.
You do not have a groupID (Org) in the path.
In your case the correct file path should be:
perf-local-gradle/YOUR/ORG/cucumber-performance-testing-framework/1.0/cucumber-performance-testing-framework-1.0.jar

instead of:
perf-local-gradle/cucumber-performance-testing-framework/1.0/cucumber-performance-testing-framework-1.0.jar

You can read more about repo layouts here:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Layouts